# NFC Tag reverse engineering failed by a non-responding tag

Tags: hardware, protocol

I was curious about a system using NFC and I tried to find out what was the protocol. But after digging few days around, I have the card detected by my reader (acr122u) but that's all I get. I can't have any answer from the card.

```
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
NFC device: ACS / ACR122U PICC Interface opened
1 ISO14443B-2 ST SRx passive target(s) found:
ISO/IEC 14443-2B ST SRx (106 kbps) target:
            UID: 9a  87  18  4e  XX  XX  XX  XX
```

How can I get more informations on it ? Is it possible this card was only giving its UID ?

Answer (score 2):

Some RFID cards indeed only provide their IDs. IDs are then matched to a database to say, decide if a door should be opened. It's really up to the card.

The two ways I can think of to identify the card's capabilities is either traced it back to the manufacturer (who bought it? What model/type of card was it?) or break it and find the chip and look at it under a microscope.